# Dar resize num vector em Matlab

Tags: array, matriz, matlab

Boa tarde. É o seguinte,usei a seguinte função para criar um vetor vazio que guarda mais tarde certos valores pedidos ao utilizador:

```
fragil = zeros(1, 10); %criaçao do vetor
idF = str2double(input('Insira um número inteiro!: ', 's')); % pedido de input
fragil(1,k)=idF; %guarda o valor no vetor
```

Porem, quando o numero de valores inseridos é menor que 10, o array vai ficar com os restantes valores a 0 e depois quando tento ir buscar os valores do array para usar numa comparação tenho a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> Index in position 2 is invalid. Array indices must be positive
>   integers or logical values.
>
> Error in Passo0 (line 40)
>
> if MCobertura(m,idosoF)==1

A minha duvida consiste(ou nao) em duas partes: 1- Como posso "limpar" os valores nulos das posiçoes nao usadas no vetor. 2-Se a mensagem de erro nao estiver associada a este detalhe, qual sera o problema. De seguida encontra-se o excerto de código onde é identificado o erro.

```
for l=1:k
    verificaF=0;
    idosoF= fragil(1,l);
    for m=1:numAmbulancias
        if MCobertura(m,idosoF)==1
            verificaF=verificaF+1;
        end
    end
    if verificaF<2
        haSolucao=false;
        break;
    end
```

Em que **k** corresponde ao numero de inputs feitos pelo utilizador, numAmbulancias corresponde às linhas da MCobertura e idosoF a coluna da MCobertura correspondente ao idoso fragilizado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A primeira pergunta é relativamente simples de resolver.

Caso você tenha certeza em ter valores diferentes de zero no seu `idF`, isto se torna simples.
Bastar usar um comparativo a matrix como índice. Abaixo coloquei uns exemplos da matrix `fragil` e como os indices se comportam.
Use a ultima linha de código abaixo antes de passar pra a próxima parte.

```
fragil =
     5     3     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
fragil~=0
ans =
     1     1     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
fragil(fragil~=0)
ans =
     5     3     1
%%% PARTE RELEVANTE DO CÓDIGO IMPORTANTE
fragil=fragil(fragil~=0)
fragil =
     5     3     0     1
```

Caso você tenha que aceitar zero como entradas, você precisa colocar um contador de entradas. 
Mas creio que você já tenha isso, pois você utiliza `k` na primeira parte do código, mas este não está declarado na funções acima. Como ele é o número de inputs, basta utilizar

```
fragil =
     5     3     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
k =
4
fragil=fragil(1,1:k)
fragil =
     5     3     0     1
```

---

A segunda questão gira em torno de:

> Array indices must be positive integers or logical values.

Este erro diz que você está colocando um valor escalar como índice da matrix.
Isso significa que você pode estar colocando um valor não inteiro (e.g. `1.2`) ou então `0`. Veja que a sua entrada em

```
idF = str2double(input('Insira um número inteiro!: ', 's')); % pedido de input
```

não elimina a possibilidade de alguém colocar um valor real (e.g. `3.14`).
Uma solucão seria usar `round(str2double(input()))` pra ter certeza que são inteiros e usar a minha solucão anterior para remover os zeros.

De resto fica difícil testar seu código, pois você ele está colocado em uma maneira a depender das entradas, sejam elas `0` ou não, você pode limitar pelo valor de `k`, mas se o input for `0`, ele vai dar problemas. Para resolver isso, você precisa mudar o seu método.

Caso o código tenha `k=1` e cada vez que tem um input `k=k+1`, depois do ultimo input, a valor será igual ao `número_de_inputs + 1` . Se este for o caso, apenas subtraia 1 de `k` quando não tiver mais inputs.